# SQL - Update if all bool values for an id are true

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

task: (t_id is a primary key, all_done is boolean)

```
+------+-------------+
| t_id |    all_done |
+------+-------------+
|    1 |           0 |
|    2 |           0 |
+------+-------------+
```

subtask: (s_id is a primary key, done is boolean)

```
+------+------------+
| s_id |       done |
+------+------------+
|    1 |          0 |
|    2 |          0 |
|    3 |          1 |
|    4 |          1 |
|    5 |          1 |
|    6 |          0 |
|    7 |          0 |
+------+------------+
```

task_subtask: (s_id and t_id are foreign keys. not every subtask belongs to a task)

```
+------+------+
| t_id | s_id |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    2 |    4 |
|    2 |    5 |
+------+------+
```

The table *task_subtask* shows which subtask belongs to which task.
My intention is to make an sql-call to set *all_done = 1* if all subtasks of that task are done. So in this example *all_done* should be set to 1 for *t_id = 2*

The following code seems to work, but i can't manage to fill this into an UPDATE call and i'm not really sure if i'm thinking into the right direction:

```
SELECT x.t_id, count(x.t_id), SUM(x.done) FROM (
    SELECT subtask.s_id, subtask.done, task_subtask.t_id FROM subtask JOIN task_subtask WHERE subtask.s_id = task_subtask.s_id
) AS x GROUP BY x.t_id;
```

With that statement i'd get this output:

```
+------+---------------+-------------+
| t_id | count(x.t_id) | SUM(x.done) |
+------+---------------+-------------+
|    1 |             3 |           1 |
|    2 |             2 |           2 |
+------+---------------+-------------+
```

My best try might have been this:

```
UPDATE task, (SELECT x.t_id, count(x.t_id), SUM(x.done) FROM (
        SELECT subtask.s_id, subtask.done, task_subtask.t_id FROM subtask JOIN task_subtask WHERE subtask.s_id = task_subtask.s_id
    ) AS x GROUP BY x.t_id)
SET task.all_done = 1 WHERE task.t_id = t_id AND count(x.t_id) = SUM(x.done);
```

The error message with this call is

> ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

but i'm not sure if the update call would even work this way.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were complicating the query. I think this should work.

```
UPDATE task 
JOIN (SELECT ts.t_id 
      FROM subtask s
      JOIN task_subtask ts ON s.s_id = ts.s_id
      GROUP BY ts.t_id
      HAVING COUNT(s.s_id) = SUM(s.done) 
      ) x
ON task.t_id = x.t_id
SET all_done = 1
```

Comment: This returns an empty set

Comment: @vienya .. what do you mean? how many rows does the derived table return?

Comment: Argh, sorry. My fault. I failed to adjust the example to my real database. Now it's working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you just merge task_subtask as the same table, adding T_ID field,

task_table:

```
+------+-------------+
| t_id |    all_done |
+------+-------------+
|    1 |           0 |
|    2 |           0 |
+------+-------------+
```

subtask_table: (s_id,t_id is a primary key)

```
+------+------+------------+
| s_id | t_id |       done |
+------+-------------------+
|    1 |    1 |          0 |
|    2 |    1 |          0 |
|    3 |    1 |          1 |
|    4 |    2 |          1 |
|    5 |    2 |          1 |
 etc...
+------+------|------------+
```

Now you can try

```
UPDATE TASK SET all_done=1 WHERE 
count
    (Select done from subtask join task 
    on subtask.t_id=task.t_id WHERE done=0)=0
```

That means, for each Task, if don't have more subtask where done=0, then update Task set all_done=1

---

Another good way: Create a trigger AFTER update subTask, with the same logic above.

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_all_done
AFTER UPDATE
   ON subtask FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN    
   IF count(Select done from subtask  WHERE subtask.t_id = new.t_id)=0
then UPDATE TASK SET all_done=1 WHERE Task.t_id = new.t_id

END;
```

---

I look now and have a third solution, using just one table:

```
SELECT distinct t_id from subtask where done=0
```

This single line returns t_id not yet done, and you can use it as verification, or

```
UPDATE TASK SET all_done=1 WHERE t_id NOT in (SELECT distinct t_id from subtask where done=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but since i can't adjust the tables in this case the solution from @vkp suits me better.